# Finding function that satisfies conditions

Tags: integration, functions

More than a solution, I hope to learn the standard approach to these problems. In this specific example, I aim to find a continuous non-piecewise function $S(x)$ where:

1. $S(0){=}1/4$
2. $S(1){=}1/2$
3. $\int^{1}_{0}S(x)~{\rm d}x {=} 1/4$
4. $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} S(x) {=} 1$

What is the standard approach? Is there a way of knowing if such a function even exists? Can you know if the result is degenerate (i.e., there are non-unique solutions)?

**-Note 1-**

All my attempts are based on trial and error. My best solution is $S(x){=}(x+1/2)/(x+2)$, which satisfies conditions (1), (2), and (4). It does not satisfy condition (3). I do not know of a more rigorous approach.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note:  I suppose you meant to add the assumption that $S$ is continuous?  Otherwise, you can find a step function that works.

Comment: The first 3 condition involve $S(x)$ only for $x <1$, so take $S(x)=1$ for $x \geq 1$. Try to answer the question now.

Comment: @lulu I added 'continuous' to the question. I am not sure what the approach would be. I ended up using trial and error and the best I could find is $S(x){=}(x+1/2)/(x+2)$.

Comment: I wouldn't look for a rational function (though it's possible there is one).  Try a piecewise linear one.  Much easier.

Comment: The conditions are really simple. Imagining such a function shouldn't be hard  if you understand what each of those conditions means: Take a line segment from $(0,1/4)$ to $(1/2, a)$ and another segment from $(1/2,a)$ to $(1,1/2)$. Pick $a$ such that the integral is $1$, to do that you just calculate the area of a very simple polygon in terms of $a$, set it equal to $1$ and solve for $a$. That already satisfies the first three conditions.

Comment: @jjagmath Your solution, whereas practical, does not yield a continuous function.

Comment: The function I described is continuous. Its graph are two segments with a common endpoint, that's obviously the graph of a continuous function.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, you're right. I am looking for a single function with one equation as opposed to a sort of spline. Your answer would seem to produce a piecewise function, right?

Comment: Yes, and very easily you can extend it to satisfy the fourth condition.

Comment: What is a continuous singular function? And why is there a linear algebra tag?

Answer (score 1):

How about $S = 1+ ae^{-x} + be^{-2x} + ce^{-3x}$

I chose exponentials to make sure $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} S(x) = 1$

Setting $S(0) = \frac 14, S(1) = \frac 12$ and $\int_0^1 S(x)\ dx = \frac 14$ will generate a system of linear equations.

Comment: You probably meant $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} S(x) = 1$

Comment: Yes, I had the integral evaluating to 1 as well, those numbers were transposed.  Thanks.

Comment: The coefficients get a little messy but it's a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$S(x)=\frac{5-x}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|-\frac{1}{8}\left|x-1\right|-\frac{1}{4}|x-2|$$